# Is this statement about functions expressed as infinite products true?

Tags: infinite-product

Let $f$ be a function of $x$ that respects these conditions: $f(a_n)=0,f(0)=1, n \in [1,\infty) $. From this, can we express the function $f$ as an infinite product? If so, is this statement true?

$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x}{a_n}\right)$$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: Sometimes true.  But sometimes that series does not converge, and it needs help.  As in the @lhr link.  You may learn this in the future when you take a course in complex analysis.